# numpy.array operation / method: subtract value of one element from the value of next element

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to build the differences from the values of one element [n] to the next element [n+1] in the same `numpy.array`.

This must be repeated for all n, I expect n-1 result values.
Furthermore I want to avoid using loops, because loops may be a source of errors numbering the elements.

Now I'm looking for an operation like:

```
result = array[n+1] - array[n]
```

for all `n`.

I tried much similar implementations, but I always get some error messages.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, you might want to take a look at how to format code so that it is readable and copy-pastable. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are the guidelines to ask a good question. As for the answer itself, `np.diff(array)` does what you ask

Comment: np.diff() is what I looked for. Sometimes it is very easy with one keyword from an expert. Thank you gionni!

Comment: You are welcome pal, it can be hard to find what you are looking for in the beginning ;-)

Comment: @gionni You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy's [`diff()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) function does what you ask.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)  # this instantiates a numpy array containing values from 0 to 9
result = np.diff(a)  # if you print this you'll see an array of 1 with length 9
```

If you want you can use slicing instead (I add this for all newbies, as an example of [slicing](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)), as follows:

```
result = a[1:] - a[:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = np.array([2,3,1,0])
result = x[:-1] - x[1:]
```

Output:

```
[-1,  2,  1]
```